# What is a doubly periodic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

We have introduced the notion of a doubly periodic function. But I somehow struggle a bit in understanding it.

> $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is called doubly periodic if there exists $w_0,w_1\in \Bbb{C}$ such that they are linearly independent over $R$ and $$f(z+w_0)=f(z+w_1)=f(z)$$ for all $z$.

I somehow don't see how I can apply the real valued function $f$ to $z+w_0$ which is a complex number.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to first use analytic continuation to extend $\,f\,$ to the entire complex plane.

Comment: @Somos sorry I have never heard about that. Could you maybe explain this a bit more?

Comment: Perhaps whoever wrote this intended to write $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$.  The notion really applies to functions of a complex variable, not a real one.

Comment: @lulu so I don't know because this is a definition given from our Prof.

Comment: Well, I'd ask about it.  People make mistakes all the time.  As it stands, what you wrote doesn't really make sense as $f(z+\omega_i)$ is generally undefined.

Comment: So you mean that $f:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ and then i take $w_0=a+bi,w_1=c+di\in \Bbb{C}$ such that the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are linearly independent?

Comment: @lulu or is there an other meaning of linearly independece over $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Linearly independent over the reals, yes.  This is a very standard notion in complex analysis.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_periodic_function) for instance.

Comment: For complex numbers $\omega_1,\omega_2$ to be linearly independent over $\mathbb R$ you really just require that they aren't real multiples of one another.

Comment: @lulu so but it is equivalent to consider the real and imaginary part as a vector and say that $\not \exists \lambda \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\lambda (a,b)=(c,d)$ or saying that there exists no $\alpha, \alpha' \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\alpha \cdot a=c$ and $\alpha' \cdot b=d$ right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Comment: @lulu would it be possible for you also to help me here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408453/why-is-a-doubly-periodic-function-always-bounded?